# Proving the other directon of the Ky-Fan's inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

*Ky-Fan's inequality* states that given two symmetric matricies $A,B$
$$\forall k=1,...,n: \sum_{i=1}^{k}{\lambda_{i}(A+B)} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}{\lambda_{i}(A) + \lambda_{i}(B)}$$

I am trying to prove the following inequality

$$\forall k=1,...,n: \sum_{i=1}^{k}{\lambda_{n-i+1}(A+B)} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{k}{\lambda_{n-i+1}(A) + \lambda_{n-i+1}(B)}$$

I thought about using the *Minmax Principle* where:
$$\lambda_k(A) = \max_{V:dimV=k} \min_{x \in V , ||x||_2=1} x^TAx$$
and I got to the point where
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}{\lambda_{n-i+1}(A+B)} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}{\max_{V:dimV=k} \min_{x \in V , ||x||_2=1} x^TAx+x^TBx}$$
however, I don't know if this the correct direction or where to go from here.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply apply Ky-Fan's inequality to $-A$, $-B$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_{n - i + 1} (A + B) &= 
-\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_{i} (-A - B)
\\ &\geq -\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_{i} (-A) + \lambda_i(-B)
= \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_{n-i+1}(A) + \lambda_{n-i+1}(B).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Aa me From your edit, it looks like you misunderstood my answer. The fact that the indices change as we switch the sign of the matrices is the entire point

Comment: Yep, it seems that I have misunderstood your answer, could you elaborate more on why the equality is true? (change of indices)

Comment: @Aame The key is that $\lambda_{i}(-A) = -\lambda_{n-i+1}(A)$. If $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ in decreasing order, then $-\lambda_n,\dots,-\lambda_1$ are the eigenvalues of $-A$ in decreasing order.